# Simplest way to append data to a SQL Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm sure i can figure something out using `replace`, etc, but just wondering if there is anything out there that lets you simply append data to a column rather than how the common `Insert` function works?

Well I guess i can do `INSERT INTO TABLE (NAME) SELECT Name + @Name` right?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to do?  It's hard to follow what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What is more simple than `update tab set col = col + 'addon'`?

Comment: You mean like `UPDATE Tbl SET Col = Col + 'suffix' WHERE ...` ?

Comment: What does "append data to a column" mean?

Comment: @ZeeTee Not trying to bash you.  People are here to help others.  For free.  It's just courteous for you to be as clear as possible about your requirements when you post a question.

Comment: If you're trying to append data to every single value in a column, as a couple of the answers have presumed, there is no reason to store that in the table for every single row. You could use a computed column, or a view, or just hard-code the append string in your query. Also asking for clarification on your question is not bashing you. It's trying to help you accurately without having to have a meeting about what you meant.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Without more details, here's a simple example:

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn = YourColumn + 'Appended Data'
```

Comment: Can also use `SET YourColumn += 'Appended Data'` in 2008

Comment: +1 to both answer and comment. However I try to keep myself from using the shorthand syntax because not all future readers will notice the tag or subsequent comments, and then will complain when SQL Server 2005 doesn't like the syntax. Has happened to me at least a dozen times (and I probably still use += from time to time, as well as `DECLARE @x INT = 1;`).

Comment: For anyone wondering how to do this in Oracle, the operator is `||` and so looks like this: `UPDATE YourTable SET YourColumn = YourColumn || 'Appended Data'`

Answer (score 9):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but here is an example with a table named Names with two columns: id - int, name - nvarchar(max):

```
update Names
set name = name + ' a string to append'
where id = 2
```

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn += 'Appended Data'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but the following illustrates how to use string concatenation to append "newValue" when a particular condition is satisfied:

UPDATE [nameOfTable] SET [columnName] += "newValue" where [id]=[value]